# "install zip from sd card" missing on Samsung Ace

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, device-firmware, recovery-mode

When I go into the recovery mode I am missing the option "install zip from sd card". I have installed the Android 2.3.6 DDKQ8 Fimware (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7L_w-MNxAzE). How can I get this option to appear?

Comment: Have you installed a custom recovery image, or are you using the one that came pre-installed on your device?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Have you installed clockworkmod ?